# Mailchimp post request in react giving error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am making my web using React no backend. I want to integrate MailChimp to my app but it's giving me the following error:

> ContactUs.jsx:40 POST http://localhost:3000/3.0/lists/{api-key} 404 (Not Found)

```
function sendData(event) {
    const { name, email, subject } = state;
    const userData = {
        members: [
            {
                "email_address": email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    "FNAME": name,
                    "MESSAGE": subject,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    console.log(userData)
    fetch('/3.0/lists/{api-key}', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'auth': "saad:153b-us12",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
            userData
        )
    }).then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: on top of the other answer, {api-key} should be replaced by your actual api key

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the request to the localhost, which is your app url on your machine. According to the Mailchnimp docs you should send the request to `https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com` url. Just set the correct url in the fetch function.